# SVG Filter not showing in any browser

Tags: svg

Hello I'm new to SVG and tryed to follow a tutorial.
My problem is that the SVG filter is not showing on the object.
(when you click the object it should give an animation)

I hope somebody could help me with this problem.

link to code: codepen.io/sanderman789/pen/yVYvRL

Comment: Your filter is called filter-goo-2, however all your references refer to a filter with id="filter".

Comment: I renamed everything correctly and it still doenst work.